# How to create a grain / noise effect in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

I want to create a noise effect using Adobe Illustrator.

Inside the hexagonal shape there is some kind of texture effect, I don't know what the name of this effect is:

[image]

How can I create such an effect in Adobe Illustrator? or is it created using Photoshop?

Comment: Related: [How to apply, blend or overlay a texture or pattern image to a layer in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19555/how-to-apply-blend-or-overlay-a-texture-or-pattern-image-to-a-layer-in-photosho)

Answer (score 13):

In Illustrator.... Effect > Texture > Grain

[image]

Comment: How to make the grains monotone?

Answer (score 4):

use **Effects > artistic > film grain**

keep hilighted areas at max and tweak the other settings

you will get better grain that the usual **texture > grain**

Answer (score 3):

You can create this in Illustrator, but this is Photoshop's wheelhouse. Raster effects is where Photoshop excels. I honestly would look for a texture via sites like [Texture King](http://www.textureking.com/) and then apply those effects in masked layers (maybe even using some blending modes), but you can create simpler texture effects with the use of Photoshop effects.