# Trying to create a blackboard texture and gradient in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I'm trying to create a wedding invitation but I'm struggling to get the same effect as the example one I've seen on a website.

How would I create the same background effect? I've tried using the gradient tool in Photoshop, but it doesn't seem to create the same effect.

[image: Example invitation]

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the gradient in the duplicate question, it would help if you used something like the [overlay blend mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html) with some kind of [chakckboard texture](http://www.photoshopbuzz.com/create-chalk-board-background/).

Comment: Thank you Jenna, the chalkboard texture helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Jenna If you'd post that as an answer, I'd upvote it! :)

Comment: At work currently will post answer later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do 2 different things. The first is create a [chalkboard texture](http://www.photoshopbuzz.com/create-chalk-board-background/).

In short - using the filters tab - render clouds, add noise, add gaussian blur.

The second (optional) is to create a [gradient](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/gradients.html) and apply the [blend mode overlay](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html) so that your texture will still show through.

Hope this has been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could also find a photo of decent resolution that has the texture you want, overlay that onto your black or dark gray background and then change the layer's transparency setting to multiply or overlay and then adjust the opacity or fill to get the look you want.

Here's a little different, but related exercise
[How to apply, blend or overlay a texture or pattern image to a layer in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19555/how-to-apply-blend-or-overlay-a-texture-or-pattern-image-to-a-layer-in-photosho)

There are many different ways to achieve this effect, find the one that works best for you.